# holomorphic sections dependence on degree

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

If the degree of a complex line bundle with respect to an integral Kahler form
is negative will the number of global holomorphic sections of the bundle  with respect to any
holomorphic structure be zero.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. For an elementary proof, see the bottom half of p. 155 of Griffiths/Harris.

Comment: Crossposted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/303229.